# Is there a way to detect if a user drops more than one file on my C# icon?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I have a program that takes a command line argument when a file is dropped on its icon.
I want to detect and prevent the user from dropping more than one file on it at a time.
The  program seems to only grab one file to work with but that file seems to be random.
Is this possible? Below is how I'm doing it...

```
    foreach (string arg in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
    {
        cmdLine = (arg);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Evironment.GetCommandLineArgs should return an array of strings if multiple files are dropped on the exe which you can then iterate through...

```
var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
if(args.Length > 0) {
    foreach(var s in args) {
       Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```